# Build Runnable Jar of a JAVA project with JAVAFX as external lib

Tags: swing, javafx, build

I have a project with a Swing java main class. 
In this class I create an object represented by another class that extends Application and uses JAVAFX.
In Eclipse i have imported all the necessary lib of JAVAFX and when i run the JAVA project all works well.

My problem arises when i want to build all project into a runnable jar. Jar is built without error, all Java classes works and only JAVAFX class does not. 
I don't understand how build a Java project with external JAVAFX class and dependencies into a single jar so that everything works. Any suggestions? i tried a lot without results...

if you need some piece of code or some information about the project settings I will be happy to write them. Thanks in advice.

I also tried with Maven :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>AvalonMikGiu</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>11</javafx.version>
    </properties>

  <name>AvalonMikGiu</name>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>linux</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>mac</classifier>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>linux</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>mac</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>linux</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>mac</classifier>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>linux</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>mac</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>linux</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>mac</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>linux</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>mac</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>linux</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>mac</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
              <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.0.3</version>
              <configuration>
                  <mainClass>src.QuickFlip2</mainClass>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>project-classifier</shadedClassifierName>
                        <outputFile>shade\${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation=
                                                 "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>src.MainGame</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Build works well but when i launch jar file i obtain this error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MainGame
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainGame
```

I don't understand why don't find my mainclass..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a simple solution: (Eclipse)**

1. Delete class that extend Application and import the methods into the
   Java class
2. Include the JavaFX libraris in Eclipse project and import them in Java class
3. Export project in Runnable Jar, select handling : "Copy required
   libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR"
4. Once exported, next step is :

**Windows :**

> copy the javafx-sdk-"version"/bin folder into same folder of
>   project.jar and procjet_lib (if use images in project copy the
>   folder_img near them)
>
> (JavaFX lib folder should already have been included in the project_lib folder by eclipse)

**MAC/LINUX :**

> they doesn't have the JavaFX bin folder so then copy all files in
>   JavaFX lib folder into your project_lib (overwrite.. probably jar file
>   are duplicate).

NB. download the right jdk JavaFX package, name is like :
openjfx-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin-sdk
openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk
openjfx-11.0.2_osx-x64_bin-sdk